# importing data from excel to R via psych::read.clipboard

Tags: r, excel

I am trying to streamline a process by which I select and copy two columns from an excel worksheet and import them into R, where I further subset them.  Here is my issue:

The excel data has multiple sets of data in the same column.  So for example: column 1 is [V,1,2,3,4,V,1,2,3,4] and column two is [A,2,4,6,10,A,3,6,9,12] where V and A are the column headers.  I tried copying the two relevant columns, then running the following code in R:

```
testing<-read.clipboard(header=TRUE, sep="  ")
testinga<-testing[1:4,]
```

the resulting table looks fine, but when plotted in ggplot

```
 ggplot(testing, aes(V,A))+geom_point()
```

resulting graphs orders my data points by the first number (i.e. the 10 is plotted as a 1)

This is NOT an issue if I simply copy the first data set and import it using read.clipboard

What is going on here, and how do I get around it?

#### Edit:

```
# from dput()
testing <- structure(list(V = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "V"), class = "factor"), A = structure(c(3L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 2L), .Label = c("10", "12", "2", "3", "4", "6", "9", "A"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V", "A"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: Can you post `dput(testing)` in your question so we can see what the data looks like?

Comment: dput(testing): structure(list(V = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "V"), class = "factor"), 
    A = structure(c(3L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 2L), .Label = c("10", 
    "12", "2", "3", "4", "6", "9", "A"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V", "A"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

Comment: If I copy only the first data set, I get:   dput(testingb): structure(list(V = 1:4, A = c(2L, 4L, 6L, 10L)), .Names = c("V", 
"A"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

Comment: Note this question seems to apply to an earlier version of {psych}. psych version 2.2.5 no longer includes this function.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the big data.frame's columns get converted to factors (not numerics) if there are things other than numbers in them, like more column names. You just need to convert back to numeric.

```
testinga <- testing[1:4, ]
testinga <- sapply(testinga, FUN = function(x){as.numeric(as.character(x))})
```

Then you should be able to plot just fine.

Comment: Thanks - however, when I tried this, I got the following error:  "Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class matrix" is there any way to get around this?

Comment: `as.data.frame(testinga)`